# Core plot Axes difficulty

Tags: core-plot

I am plotting Unix Timestamps vs weights, and so my x axis range, as an example, is:
1380330622 thru 1382696991

Y axis is: 83 thru 86 or so...

There are 40 entries.

My plot range is basically set up to the min<->max of each, and the graph data shows up fine... but I can't get my Axes to show up at all...

Initially the high x axis numbers were causing a huge number of major tick to be allocated, thats solved, but no axes:

[image]

```
    -(void)configureAxis{


    graph.plotAreaFrame.axisSet.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];

    // Line styles
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 3.0;
    axisLineStyle.lineCap   = kCGLineCapRound;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75;
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.25;
    minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blueColor];

    // Text styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica Bold";
    axisTitleTextStyle.fontSize = 14.0;

    // Axes
    // Label x axis with a fixed interval policy
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.separateLayers              = NO;
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(82.0f);
    x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"86400");
    x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 4;
    x.tickDirection               = CPTSignNone;
    x.axisLineStyle               = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorTickLength             = 12.0;
    x.majorTickLineStyle          = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
    x.minorTickLength             = 8.0;
    x.minorGridLineStyle          = minorGridLineStyle;
    x.title                       = @"Date";
    x.titleTextStyle              = axisTitleTextStyle;
    x.titleOffset                 = 25.0;
    x.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;


    // Label y axis with a fixed interval policy
    CPTXYAxis *y          = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.separateLayers              = NO;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(1380340622.0f);
    y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"10");
    y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 4;
    y.tickDirection               = CPTSignNone;
    y.axisLineStyle               = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorTickLength             = 12.0;
    y.majorTickLineStyle          = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
    y.minorTickLength             = 8.0;
    y.minorGridLineStyle          = minorGridLineStyle;
    y.title                       = @"Weight in kg";
    y.titleTextStyle              = axisTitleTextStyle;
    y.titleOffset                 = 25.0;
    y.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;





}
```

Here is the current output with numberforplot:

```
    2013-10-26 11:13:04.509 app[2174:303] The size of the arays for x and y are: 41;41
2013-10-26 11:13:04.509 app[2174:303] XMIN: 111667.172778  XMAX: 112324.4975
2013-10-26 11:13:04.509 app[2174:303] YMIN: 83.225  YMAX: 85.701
2013-10-26 11:13:04.509 app[2174:303] Data dictionary: {
    identifier = WEIGHT;
    "max_x" = "112324.4975";
    "max_y" = "85.701";
    "min_x" = "111667.172778";
    "min_y" = "83.225";
    "x_values" =     (
        "111667.172778",
        "111732.579167",
        "111732.931944",
        "111733.087222",
        "111748.680278",
        "111757.177778",
        "111760.608056",
        "111763.109444",
        "111763.497222",
        "111763.529167",
        "111763.678056",
        "111764.11",
        "111772.890556",
        "111773.146389",
        "111779.491389",
        "111785.4075",
        "111796.832778",
        "111821.3",
        "111846.429722",
        "111869.016389",
        "111892.786389",
        "111916.811111",
        "111941.981944",
        "111942.026389",
        "111965.135833",
        "111989.396667",
        "112012.848611",
        "112038.682778",
        "112061.785",
        "112085.694444",
        "112109.053056",
        "112131.653889",
        "112157.381111",
        "112181.126944",
        "112205.423056",
        "112205.711111",
        "112229.128056",
        "112252.898611",
        "112276.948889",
        "112300.449167",
        "112324.4975"
    );
    "y_values" =     (
        "83.823",
        "84.286",
        "83.807",
        "84.387",
        "83.256",
        "84.799",
        "85.005",
        "85.399",
        "85.414",
        "85.595",
        "85.701",
        "85.493",
        "84.427",
        "83.989",
        "84.462",
        "85.134",
        "83.797",
        "83.454",
        "83.87",
        "83.526",
        "83.512",
        "83.969",
        "84.02",
        "84.009",
        "85.13",
        "84.662",
        "83.869",
        "84.5",
        "83.94",
        "83.225",
        "84.352",
        "84.332",
        "83.617",
        "83.776",
        "84.582",
        "83.869",
        "83.712",
        "84.144",
        "84.048",
        "84.035",
        "84.06"
    );
}
2013-10-26 11:13:04.511 app[2174:303] Adding plot to graph system
2013-10-26 11:13:04.511 app[2174:303] Added... 1
2013-10-26 11:13:04.512 app[2174:303] Number of entries... 41
2013-10-26 11:13:04.512 app[2174:303] Number of entries... 41
2013-10-26 11:13:04.512 app[2174:303] 0,111667.172778
2013-10-26 11:13:04.513 app[2174:303] 1,111732.579167
2013-10-26 11:13:04.513 app[2174:303] 2,111732.931944
2013-10-26 11:13:04.513 app[2174:303] 3,111733.087222
2013-10-26 11:13:04.513 app[2174:303] 4,111748.680278
2013-10-26 11:13:04.513 app[2174:303] 5,111757.177778
2013-10-26 11:13:04.514 app[2174:303] 6,111760.608056
2013-10-26 11:13:04.514 app[2174:303] 7,111763.109444
2013-10-26 11:13:04.514 app[2174:303] 8,111763.497222
2013-10-26 11:13:04.514 app[2174:303] 9,111763.529167
2013-10-26 11:13:04.515 app[2174:303] 10,111763.678056
2013-10-26 11:13:04.515 app[2174:303] 11,111764.11
2013-10-26 11:13:04.515 app[2174:303] 12,111772.890556
2013-10-26 11:13:04.515 app[2174:303] 13,111773.146389
2013-10-26 11:13:04.515 app[2174:303] 14,111779.491389
2013-10-26 11:13:04.516 app[2174:303] 15,111785.4075
2013-10-26 11:13:04.516 app[2174:303] 16,111796.832778
2013-10-26 11:13:04.516 app[2174:303] 17,111821.3
2013-10-26 11:13:04.516 app[2174:303] 18,111846.429722
2013-10-26 11:13:04.516 app[2174:303] 19,111869.016389
2013-10-26 11:13:04.517 app[2174:303] 20,111892.786389
2013-10-26 11:13:04.517 app[2174:303] 21,111916.811111
2013-10-26 11:13:04.517 app[2174:303] 22,111941.981944
2013-10-26 11:13:04.517 app[2174:303] 23,111942.026389
2013-10-26 11:13:04.517 app[2174:303] 24,111965.135833
2013-10-26 11:13:04.518 app[2174:303] 25,111989.396667
2013-10-26 11:13:04.518 app[2174:303] 26,112012.848611
2013-10-26 11:13:04.518 app[2174:303] 27,112038.682778
2013-10-26 11:13:04.518 app[2174:303] 28,112061.785
2013-10-26 11:13:04.518 app[2174:303] 29,112085.694444
2013-10-26 11:13:04.518 app[2174:303] 30,112109.053056
2013-10-26 11:13:04.519 app[2174:303] 31,112131.653889
2013-10-26 11:13:04.519 app[2174:303] 32,112157.381111
2013-10-26 11:13:04.519 app[2174:303] 33,112181.126944
2013-10-26 11:13:04.519 app[2174:303] 34,112205.423056
2013-10-26 11:13:04.519 app[2174:303] 35,112205.711111
2013-10-26 11:13:04.520 app[2174:303] 36,112229.128056
2013-10-26 11:13:04.520 app[2174:303] 37,112252.898611
2013-10-26 11:13:04.520 app[2174:303] 38,112276.948889
2013-10-26 11:13:04.520 app[2174:303] 39,112300.449167
2013-10-26 11:13:04.520 app[2174:303] 40,112324.4975
2013-10-26 11:13:04.521 app[2174:303] Number of entries... 41
2013-10-26 11:13:04.521 app[2174:303] 0,83.823
2013-10-26 11:13:04.521 app[2174:303] 1,84.286
2013-10-26 11:13:04.522 app[2174:303] 2,83.807
2013-10-26 11:13:04.522 app[2174:303] 3,84.387
2013-10-26 11:13:04.522 app[2174:303] 4,83.256
2013-10-26 11:13:04.522 app[2174:303] 5,84.799
2013-10-26 11:13:04.522 app[2174:303] 6,85.005
2013-10-26 11:13:04.523 app[2174:303] 7,85.399
2013-10-26 11:13:04.523 app[2174:303] 8,85.414
2013-10-26 11:13:04.523 app[2174:303] 9,85.595
2013-10-26 11:13:04.523 app[2174:303] 10,85.701
2013-10-26 11:13:04.523 app[2174:303] 11,85.493
2013-10-26 11:13:04.524 app[2174:303] 12,84.427
2013-10-26 11:13:04.524 app[2174:303] 13,83.989
2013-10-26 11:13:04.524 app[2174:303] 14,84.462
2013-10-26 11:13:04.524 app[2174:303] 15,85.134
2013-10-26 11:13:04.524 app[2174:303] 16,83.797
2013-10-26 11:13:04.525 app[2174:303] 17,83.454
2013-10-26 11:13:04.525 app[2174:303] 18,83.87
2013-10-26 11:13:04.525 app[2174:303] 19,83.526
2013-10-26 11:13:04.525 app[2174:303] 20,83.512
2013-10-26 11:13:04.526 app[2174:303] 21,83.969
2013-10-26 11:13:04.526 app[2174:303] 22,84.02
2013-10-26 11:13:04.526 app[2174:303] 23,84.009
2013-10-26 11:13:04.526 app[2174:303] 24,85.13
2013-10-26 11:13:04.526 app[2174:303] 25,84.662
2013-10-26 11:13:04.526 app[2174:303] 26,83.869
2013-10-26 11:13:04.527 app[2174:303] 27,84.5
2013-10-26 11:13:04.527 app[2174:303] 28,83.94
2013-10-26 11:13:04.527 app[2174:303] 29,83.225
2013-10-26 11:13:04.527 app[2174:303] 30,84.352
2013-10-26 11:13:04.528 app[2174:303] 31,84.332
2013-10-26 11:13:04.528 app[2174:303] 32,83.617
2013-10-26 11:13:04.528 app[2174:303] 33,83.776
2013-10-26 11:13:04.528 app[2174:303] 34,84.582
2013-10-26 11:13:04.528 app[2174:303] 35,83.869
2013-10-26 11:13:04.529 app[2174:303] 36,83.712
2013-10-26 11:13:04.529 app[2174:303] 37,84.144
2013-10-26 11:13:04.529 app[2174:303] 38,84.048
2013-10-26 11:13:04.529 app[2174:303] 39,84.035
2013-10-26 11:13:04.529 app[2174:303] 40,84.06
2013-10-26 11:13:04.530 app[2174:303] Number of entries... 41
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is at least part of the problem: `CPTDecimalFromDouble(1380340622.0f);`

That number is too big to be represented exactly by a float value (forced by the "f" suffix). Unix time is an integer, so try something like this:

```
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromLong(1380330622);
```

---

Edit based on new information in the question:

Your axis locations are outside the range of the data. For example, the x-axis crosses the y-axis at y=82.0, but the plot range starts at 83.225.

```
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(y_min);
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(x_min);
```

If you always want to pin the axes to a certain spot in the plot area (e.g., one of the edges or the middle), regardless of the range of visible data, you can use axis constraints instead of the orthogonal coordinate.

```
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```

Comment: Thanks... I have fixed that, but still no juice not he Axes :-/

Comment: What are the x and y ranges? Does the data source return the timestamp or the index for the x-values?

Comment: I convert time stamps to integers. I have also now calculated hours since 2000 so the numbers are much smaller. Original ranges shown above